# Tensorflow 1.15rc2

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, conda

I want to install tensorflow-gpu 1.15rc2 in python3.7 conda environment with
`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.15rc2`

But i get
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.15rc2 (from versions: 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0, 1.15.0, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.15.5, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.12.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.15rc2`

Also i found out that there is [tensorflow-gpu 1.15.0-rc2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.15.0-rc2) but is still couldn't install it, i there a way to install this version of tf-gpu, i need it for [this project](https://github.com/RachelCmy/den2vel)

Answer (score -1):

"RC" stands for release candidate and it's a pre-release. Meaning it was super seeded by 1.15.0 when it got out.

You might want to try with `tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0` instead